# Play/Pause video onScroll in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I'm trying to achieve a functionality where on scrolling a video gets paused if it was playing and vice versa. Currently I can do it with an onClick function that sets the state true/false. But the problem is that the video keeps on playing after scrolling down till I don't click it to pause again. I want to keep the onClick feature as it is and also want to add the onScroll feature. Tried doing it with `onScroll` but not working.

```
const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  const handleVideoPress = () => {
    if (playing) {
      videoRef.current.pause();
      setPlaying(false);
    } else {
      videoRef.current.play();
      setPlaying(true);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="video">
      <video
        onClick={handleVideoPress}
        className="video__player"
        loop
        ref={videoRef}
        src={url}
      ></video>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this will stop your video from playing on any scroll event.  If you want it to stop playing if it has left the viewport you can look into using something like the [IntersectionObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to do something if it is in the viewport (play the video) or outside of the viewport (stop the video).

Note: most modern browsers won't allow Javascript to start a video unless there has been at least some user interaction with the page already.

```
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(handleScroll, 200))

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []}

  const startVideo = () => {
    videoRef.current.pause();
    setPlaying(false);
  }

  const pauseVideo = () => {
    videoRef.current.play();
    setPlaying(true);
  }

  const handleScroll = (e) => {
    if (playing) {
      pauseVideo();
    }
  }

  const handleVideoPress = () => {
    if (playing) {
      startVideo();
    } else {
      pauseVideo();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="video">
      <video
        onClick={handleVideoPress}
        className="video__player"
        loop
        ref={videoRef}
        src={url}
      ></video>
    );
}
```

I made a working example of using the `IntersectionObserver` with React's ref hooks which can be found here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-smoke-p9hmx

Please let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: says debouce is undefined. tried using Intersection observer, I wonder where I went wrong               useEffect(() => {
    let video = document.getElementById("video__player");
    let observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entry) => {
        if (entry.intersectionRatio != 1 && !playing) {
          videoRef.current.pause();
          setPlaying(true);
        } else if (playing) {
          videoRef.current.play();
          setPlaying(false);
        }
      },
      { threshold: 1 }
    );
    observer.observe(video);
    observer.unobserve(video);
  }, [playing]);

Comment: Debounce is either a function you can write yourself or you can use the lodash library. https://lodash.com/

Let me finish something up and I'll get you a working example with the IntersectionObserver API.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to a Codesandbox with a working example using the IntersectionObserver.

Comment: Also see my note on my answer about javascript handling the play/pause functionality for video/audio.

Comment: your codesandbox code works flawlessly. thanks man! but now the click function to play/pause video doesn't work anymore. I want to keep both the features..can you help me out??

Comment: sandbox work! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using **react waypoint** is works fine

````
import { Waypoint } from 'react-waypoint';

const AutomaticPlayer = function() {
 const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  const handleVideoPress = () => {
    if (playing) {
      videoRef.current.pause();
      setPlaying(false);
    } else {
      videoRef.current.play();
      setPlaying(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Waypoint 
      onEnter={handleVideoPress}
      onLeave={handleVideoPress}
    >
       <video
        onClick={handleVideoPress}
        className="video__player"
        loop
        ref={videoRef}
        src={url}
      ></video>
    </Waypoint>
  )
}```
````